# Angular dragular issues when used with tables

Tags: angularjs, dragular

Found the following issues when using dragular with tables:

1. When dragging rows, the rows get shrunk. 
   It does not happen when using them with list. We are using angular 1.6.4

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['dragularModule']);
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope,dragularService,$interval) {
    
  $scope.peoples = [
      {firstName: 'Elinor', lastName: 'Ramirez',company:'Maxiserve',occupation:'Safety inspector'},
      {firstName: 'Kathleen', lastName: 'Norton',company:'Castle Realty',occupation:'Bodyguard'},
      {firstName: 'Jay', lastName: 'Joe',company:'Jackpot Consultant',occupation:'Electronic typesetting machine operator'},
      {firstName: 'Karl', lastName: 'Lancaster',company:'Bonanza Produce Stores',occupation:'Molding, coremaking, and casting machine setter'},
      {firstName: 'Rocio', lastName: 'Roque',company:'Buena Vista Realty Service',occupation:'Social and human service assistant'},
{firstName: 'Keller', lastName: 'Mast',company:'NA',occupation:'NA'},
{firstName: 'Heeth', lastName: 'Quest',company:'NA',occupation:'NA'},
{firstName: 'Sam', lastName: 'Chester',company:'NA',occupation:'NA'},
{firstName: 'Jason', lastName: 'Miller',company:'NA',occupation:'NA'},
{firstName: 'Path', lastName: 'Kals',company:'NA',occupation:'NA'},
{firstName: 'Such', lastName: 'Rita',company:'NA',occupation:'NA'}
    ];
  
  var timer,
      scrollContainer = document.getElementById('parentContainer'),
      dragDropContainer = document.getElementById('drag-drop-zone'),
      topBar = document.getElementById('topBar'),
      bottomBar = document.getElementById('bottomBar');
  
    dragularService.cleanEnviroment();
  //initialize the DND container and model
            dragularService([dragDropContainer], {
                scope: $scope,
                containersModel: [$scope.peoples],
                lockY: true
            });
  
    registerEvents(topBar, scrollContainer, -5,20);
    registerEvents(bottomBar, scrollContainer, 5,20);
  
  function registerEvents(bar, container, inc, speed) {
      if (!speed) {
        speed = 20;
      }
      angular.element(bar).on('dragularenter', function() {
        container.scrollTop += inc;
        timer = $interval(function moveScroll() {
          container.scrollTop += inc;
        }, speed);
      });
      angular.element(bar).on('dragularleave dragularrelease', function() {
        $interval.cancel(timer);
      });
    }
  
});
```

```css
body{
  background-color:black;
  padding-top:10px;
}
table, th , td  {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  padding: 15px;
  text-align:center;
  margin-left:20%;
  
}
table th{
 background-color: blue; 
}
table tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: lightblue;
  
}
table tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
.bar{
  height:10px;
 position:fixed; 
  width: 90%;
}
.bar.topBar{
  top: 65px;
  right: 30px; 
}
.bar.bottomBar{
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<html>
<script src= "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
 <script src= "https://rawgit.com/luckylooke/dragular/master/dist/dragular.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://rawgit.com/luckylooke/dragular/master/dist/dragular.css"/>
<body id="parentContainer">

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl"> 
<div id="topBar" class="bar topBar"><div>
<table id="scrollContainer">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Company</th>
      <th>Occupation</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
   <tbody id="drag-drop-zone">
  <tr ng-repeat="person in peoples">
    <td class="handle"></td>
    <td>{{ person.firstName }}</td>
    <td>{{ person.lastName }}</td>
    <td>{{ person.company }}</td>
    <td>{{ person.occupation }}</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
  <div id="bottomBar" class="bar bottomBar"><div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

https://codepen.io/naveen_vijayaraghavan/pen/KZQLBW

2. Scroll behaves weirdly. Sometimes it just does not stop scrolling or it does not scroll at all.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with [tag:java].  Did you mean [tag:javascript]?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Ask only one question at a time. Try to provide a [minimal working code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for both

Comment: @JoeC Yes..my bad!..it was supposed to be javascript.

Comment: @Murmel pretty much a rookie in SO..will work on it..actually i just wanted to post the codepen link..but the system is not allowing me to.

Comment: @NaveenKv you need to style those elements with CSS. Dragged element gets class gu-mirror by default, so you need to play with CSS to get it right as tables have some specific behaviours. And scrolling part, you need to put table into some wrapper set to oveflow scroll and then provide the wrapper in registerEvents function as container.